# How to connect to an external display using iOS13 Swift or SwiftUI

Tags: swift, ios13, display

Maybe a bit of a newbie here, so forgive me if the an easy fix, but I have used the below code pre ios13 to display a image on an external display, but now Ive come across a warning.

The warning is 'Setter for 'screen' was deprecated in iOS 13.0'

MY CODE:

```
 @objc func setupScreen(){
            if UIScreen.screens.count > 1{

                //find the second screen
                let secondScreen = UIScreen.screens[1]
              secondScreen.overscanCompensation = .none
                //set up a window for the screen using the screens pixel dimensions
                secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: secondScreen.bounds)

                //windows require a root view controller
                let viewcontroller = UIViewController()
                secondWindow?.rootViewController = viewcontroller

                //tell the window which screen to use





                secondWindow?.screen = secondScreen




                //set the dimensions for the view for the external screen so it fills the screen
                secondScreenView = UIView(frame: secondWindow!.frame)

                //add the view to the second screens window
                secondWindow?.addSubview(secondScreenView!)

                //unhide the window
                secondWindow?.isHidden = false

                //customised the view
               let img = UIImage(named: "chart.png")
             //  view.layer.contents = img?.cgImage

                secondScreenView?.layer.contents = img?.cgImage

                // secondScreenView!.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "chart.png")!)

                secondScreenView!.addSubview(externalLabel)
            }
        }

        @objc func screenDisconnected(){
            secondWindow = nil
            secondScreenView = nil
        }

        func registerForScreenNotifications(){

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(testPatterns.setupScreen), name: UIScreen.didConnectNotification, object: nil)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(testPatterns.screenDisconnected), name: UIScreen.didDisconnectNotification, object: nil)

        }

    }
```

I tried looking in the Apple documentation but I can't find anything?

Any help would be great.

P.S it does still work but would like to get rid of the warning.

cheers!

Comment: Every deprecation has a comment what to use instead.

Comment: Hello, not this one I'm afraid. I think it might be a case that we are supposed to be using SwiftUI?